# How to build a tensor from 2 scalars in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two scalars resulting from the following operations:
`a = tf.reduce_sum(tensor1)`, `b = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tensor2), tensor3)` this is a dot product since `tensor2` and `tensor3` have the same dimensions (1-D vectors). Since these tensors have shape `[None, dim1]` it becomes difficult to deal with the shapes.

I want to build a tensor that has shape (2,1)  using `a` and `b`.

I tried `tf.Tensor([a,b], dtype=tf.float64, value_index=0)` but raises the error

`TypeError: op needs to be an Operation: [<tf.Tensor 'Sum_5:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'MatMul_67:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>]`

Any easier way to build that tensor/vector?

Comment: you wrote: `I have two scalars resulting from ... . Since these tensors have shape [None, dim1]`. So what are they scalars or vectors?

Comment: @Deigo : Did you try tf.stack version ? I am using just constants of shape None.

Comment: @SalvadorDali you are right, actually they all have the shape mentioned above `tensor1.shape = [None, dim1]` so I can have batches. So these are (should) be vectors of the size of the batch

Comment: then you should not have any problems with tf.concat or tf.stack

Answer (score 1):

This would do probably. Change axis based on what you need

```
a = tf.constant(1)
b = tf.constant(2)
c = tf.stack([a,b],axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[1],
       [2]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [concat or stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/array_ops#Slicing_and_Joining) to achieve this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
t1 = tf.constant([1])
t2 = tf.constant([2])
c = tf.reshape(tf.concat([t1, t2], 0), (2, 1))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(c)
```

In a similar way you can achieve it with `tf.stack`.

Comment: This approach is not working, I will rephrase my question since I omitted some details